# Should I change all npm packages's distag in package.json to "latest"?

Tags: npm

I'm building a boilerplate for my every frontend projects and if I wanted when I run `npm install` so all my dependencies will be the latest version, Would I change all the packages' distag to "latest" for that purpose?

```
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "latest",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1"
```

to

```
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "latest",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "latest",
        "@babel/preset-env": "latest",
        "babel-eslint": "latest"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The package-lock.json**

`npm v5.2+` comes with a `package-lock.json` file that is generated when you install packages. This file should be versioned because it contains the information of every package installed.

> The idea then becomes that instead of using package.json to resolve and install modules, npm will use the package-lock.json. Because the package-lock specifies a version, location and integrity hash for every module and each of its dependencies, the install it creates will be the same, every single time. It won’t matter what device you are on, or when in the future you install, it should give you the same result every time, which is very useful.

So, if `package-lock.json` locks down the version of installed packages, what is the problem using `"latest"`?

The problem lies in that your `package.json` is not meaningful.

- Your `package.json` does not tell you what version is actually installed, not even a clue.
- What if someone overrides the `package-lock.json` or deletes it.

It is not the end of the world, but having a `package.json` should give us a clue about the packages we have installed.

Of course you can see a list of your installed packages with versions: `npm list --depth=0` and also if you want to update packages, you can see the list of outdated ones: `npm outdated`

Check out this article: [Everything you wanted to know about package-lock.json but were too afraid to ask](https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is ok when you use lastest tag as there is no conflict in version of packages.

In the user's guide of [distag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag), they show that:

> By default, the `latest` tag is used by npm to identify the current version of a package, and `npm install <pkg>` (without any `@<version>` or `@<tag>` specifier) installs the `latest` tag. **Typically, projects only use the `latest` tag for stable release versions, and use other tags for unstable versions such as prereleases.**

So if you are gonna to release a stable version, use `latest` tag will definitely true.